# Issue with sending data with ajax to php script

Tags: php, ajax

I have an issue when sending form data over Ajax to PHP script. When sending data i get this kind of error

> Fatal Error: Class Libs\Controller not found

I have written my own MVC project structure and its working fine if i'm sending data just with POST request but when sending with AJAX getting this error

```
use Libs\Controller;

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;


class Contact extends Controller {
  //rest code to send email with PHPMailer
}
```

And here is the js script

```
$("#contact-form").on('submit', function (e) {
    $(".validmessage").css("display", "block");
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: "/../../app/controllers/Contact.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            $("#form_output").html(data);
        },
        error: function (jXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
            });
        });
```

My file structure:

```
controllers
 - Contact.php
-libraries
  - Controllers.php
  - Core.php
  - Database.php
```

Using PSR autoloader to load my classes inside index.php file

Comment: problem in your php code. ajax is just fine.

Comment: php code is working fine without sending data over ajax

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. Can you provide us with your file structure? You reach the php script but the path of your Libs\Controller is not correct.

Comment: URL should be proper eg :  url: "http://example.com/contact.php"

Comment: check this file Libs\Controller, does it exist ?

Comment: yes its exists, it's just not working when data is sent from AJAX

Comment: try using complete we address i.e. `http://host/prj/Contact.php` rather than `/../../app/controllers/Contact.php` and check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   require '../libraries/Controllers.php'

    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;


    class Contact extends Controller {
      //rest code to send email with PHPMailer
    }
```

You need to move one step back to access the Controllers. At the moment you are in `contact.php` so you can not "see" the libraries folder. You need to move 1 step back using `../` and then access the folder and it's files.